# how to call onchange only when alpha numeric values are entered in input field-reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hook-form

I don't want to allow any special characters
onChange I don't want to allow special characters and also don't want to replace empty string("")

I tried using regex

```
export const noSpecialCharacters= (input: string) =>
 input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '')
```

is there any way not to allow any special characters before onchange event occurs.

I know this is the repetitive question still, i didn't find anything apart from replacing empty string

**if i enter any special character  should not call onchange method**

problem:

if (zipcode && zipcode<4) setMessage else clear it if I get the string i am not able to display the message if I put empty check then error message will always get displayed if it is empty field also

```
 const onChangezipCode = React.useCallback(
(value: string) => {
  const FormattedValue2 = noSpecialCharacters(value)
  props.setzipcode(FormattedValue2)
  clearMessage()
  if (FormattedValue2 && FormattedValue2.length < 4) {
    setShowValidationMessage(true)
    setMessage(
      person.path,
      invalidzipcode:zipcode must be 4 digit,
    )
  }
},
[showValidationMessage, props.zipCode],
)
```

input

```
 <Input
      onChange={onChangezipCode}
      label={zipcode}
      maxLength={18}
      value={props.zipcode}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      disabled={props.readOnly}
    />
  </Input>
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your solution?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder onchange i am doing validation if (phnum && phnum<10) setMessage else clear it
if i get the string i am not able to display the message
if i put empty check then error message will always get displayed if it is empty field also

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get something is the [pattern] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) attribute, but the `onChange` would still run. `pattern`'s attr functionality will kick before submitting the form.

What you can do is wrap input in a custom component that would check the agains a regex and invoke `onChange` handler if it matches.

[Have a look at this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sunset-1ze7i?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I have edited my description, can you please tell me how to implement on those changes